# How do I get driver name on this mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this three entities mapped and related using `many-to-one` and I need to get the driver name from association in my template so I'm doing this on my template:

```
{% for devices in pagination %}
   {{ devices.getDriver.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I get this error:

> Method "getDriver" for object "Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\Device" does
>   not exist in
>   /var/www/html/src/Device/DeviceBundle/Resources/views/List/listDevices.html.twig
>   at line 47

This are the entities and mapping info:

**Device.php**

```
class Device
{

    protected $id;
    protected $description;
    protected $imei;
    protected $created;
    protected $modified;
    protected $deletedAt;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getImei()
    {
        return $this->imei;
    }

    public function setImei($imei)
    {
        $this->imei = $imei;
    }

}
```

**Mapping for Device**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                        http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\Device" table="device" repository-class="Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\Repository\DeviceRepository">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="description" column="description" type="string" length="255" unique="true" nullable="false" />
        <field name="imei" column="imei" type="string" length="17" unique="true" nullable="false" />
        <field name="created" type="datetime">
            <gedmo:timestampable on="create"/>
        </field>
        <field name="modified" type="datetime">
            <gedmo:timestampable on="update"/>
        </field>
        <field name="deletedAt" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
        <gedmo:soft-deleteable field-name="deletedAt" time-aware="false" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

**DriverHasDevice.php (the relationship entity)**

```
class DriverHasDevice
{

    protected $driver;
    protected $device;

    public function setDriver($driver)
    {
        $this->driver = $driver;
    }

    public function getDriver()
    {
        return $this->driver;
    }

    public function setDevice($device)
    {
        $this->device = $device;
    }

    public function getDevice()
    {
        return $this->device;
    }

}
```

**Mapping for DriverHasDevice**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                        http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\DriverHasDevice" table="driver_has_device">
        <id name="driver" column="driver" association-key="true" />
        <id name="device" column="device" association-key="true" />

        <many-to-one field="driver" target-entity="Driver\DriverBundle\Entity\Driver">
            <join-column name="driver" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one field="device" target-entity="Device\DeviceBundle\Entity\Device">
            <join-column name="device" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

The third entity is not relevant so I not show the code, now, how do I get driver name?

**Added method**

I added this method to `Device.php`:

```
public function getDriver()
{
    return $this->driver;
}
```

But now the error is this one:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a NULL variable ("") in
>   /var/www/html/src/Device/DeviceBundle/Resources/views/List/listDevices.html.twig
>   at line 49

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DeviceClass has no getDriver method, like it is written in the exception.
You have to implement a driver property and a getter / setter.

Further more you dont need to implement a DriverHasDevice class.
Just map the driver property of your DeviceClass to the devices property of the DriverClass

It is exactly written in the doku, just scroll down or search for "ManyToOne".
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.htm

Anyway it will work if you do the following steps:

- implement driver property
- implement getter/setter
- set the driver in your xml as ManyToOne filed with the targetEntity Driver

it will look like this:

```
<many-to-one field="driver"
        target-entity="Driver"
        inversed-by="devices"
    >
```

don't forge, if you want that your driver is aware of its devices you have to add a ArrayCollection as property and map it back to the devices.

Comment: Could you give me some help on that mapping? I tried several times and without success :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should modify your entity including `driver` protected field.

```
class Device
{
  [...]
  protected $driver
  [...]
}
```

Second you should implement `getter` and `setter` for that class property

```
class Device
{
  [...]
  public function setDriver($driver) { 
    $this->driver = $driver;

    return $this;
  }

  public function getDriver($driver) {
    return $this->driver
  }
  [...]
}
```

Third, in twig, you shouldn't try to call method directly: framework will do for you.

```
{% for devices in pagination %}
   {{ devices.driver.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I dind't verify your mapping files so you could have to modify them properly ...

Comment: I made the changes as you suggest but the same error persist `Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a NULL variable ("") in /var/www/html/src/Device/DeviceBundle/Resources/views/List/listDevices.html.twig at line 49` the values comes from the relation `driver_has_device` and from that I need to get the driver name